# Getting validationToken as null after sibscribing to outlook push notification

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am using exchangeService.SubscribeToPushNotifications to subscribe to outlook to get the latest change in calendar. My callback url gets called after subscribing but the validationToken value is null. Can any one help me?

This is my url:

public class NotifyController : ApiController
    {

```
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string validationToken = 
     null)
    {

        // If a validation token is present, we need to respond within 5 
        seconds.
        if (validationToken != null)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(validationToken);

            return response;

        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you. You should also tag the code language(s) your are using.

Comment: This is my url: